# Scheme - How to apply a recursive function to a list of variable length

Tags: recursion, scheme

Say I have a function *recurse* that takes three parameters *x,y,z*. y and z remain fixed, but x is iterative. I know how to generate a list of x values. How can I write code so that *recurse* is applied to the list of xs, but y and z remain the same?

I know *map* works like this but I don't know how to implement it considering it only works on lists of the same size. I do not know what the length of x will be. What I'm trying to do conceptually is call *recurse* on a list (x1, x2,...,xn) as such:

```
recurse x1 y z
recurse x2 y z
recurse xn y z
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be?  If you want a list back, you can wrap y and z into a lambda expression to map over x:xs.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the parameters `y` and `z` unchanged:

```
(define (recurse x y z)
  (unless (null? x)
    ;; … use x, y, z
    ;; then:
    (recurse (cdr x) y z)))
```

Alternately you can define a helper function; made easy with 'named let`:

```
(define (recurse x y z)
  (let recursing ((x x))
    ;; … use x, y, z
    ;; then:
    (recursing (cdr x))))
```

An example:

```
(define (all-in-range? values min max)
   (or (null? values)
       (and (< min (car values) max)
            (all-in-range? (cdr values) min max))))
```

Comment: the hand-coded version with logical connectives  is a nice example. :)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `map`:

```
(define (between x y z) (<= x y z))

(define (between-list xlist y z)
  (map (lambda (e) (between e y z)) xlist))

> (between-list '(1 20 3 100 99 2) 5 15)
'(#t #f #t #f #f #t)
```

As an alternative to the `lambda` function used with `map`, in Racket you can use [`curryr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=curryr#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/function..rkt%29._curryr%29%29). Also, if you just do it for side-effects, you can use `for-each` instead of `map`:

```
(define (between x y z) (display (<= x y z)))

(define (between-list xlist y z)
  (for-each (curryr between y z) xlist))

> (between-list '(1 20 3 100 99 2) 5 15)
#t#f#t#f#f#t
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a list `'(x1 x2 … xn)` and you want to apply a function `recurse` to each element `xn` as well as `y` and `z`.  You haven't said what the return value will be.  I will assume there is no return value.

```
(for-each (lambda (x) (recurse x y z)) <your list of x1, … xn>)
```

The `lambda` captures the values for `y` and `z`, takes the provided `x` argument and applies your `recurse` procedure to all three.

Answer (score 0):

You either pass the same variable to the next recursion or you leave it out completely so that it is a free variable.

Eg. send it:

```
(define (make-list items value)
  (if (zero? items)
      '()
      (cons value (make-list (- items 1) value))))
```

Have it as a free variable:

```
(define (make-list items value)
  (let loop ((items items)(acc '()))
     (if (zero? items)
         acc
         (loop (- items 1) (cons value acc)))))
```

For higher order procedures you also keep it as a free (closed over) variable:

```
(define (make-list items value)
  (map (lambda (x) value) (range items))) ;; value exists in the anonymous functions scope
```